# Use LEFT OUTER JOIN to return count even if 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return all of the specified event_abr's even if the count is 0.

Here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    basketball_event_types.event_abr,
    count(*) value
FROM
    basketball_event_types
    LEFT OUTER JOIN basketball_game_events on basketball_event_types.id = basketball_game_events.event_type_id
    LEFT JOIN users on basketball_game_events.player_id = users.id
WHERE
    users.id = 198
AND
    basketball_game_events.game_id = 213
AND
    (basketball_event_types.event_abr = "TO" OR basketball_event_types.event_abr = "AST")
GROUP BY basketball_event_types.event_abr
```

However, when I run this, the specified user (198) has 0 AST's for the specified game (213). I want AST -> 0 to pop up, but it just doesn't. The two big things I tried were adding OUTER ot the LEFT JOIN, and I also tried using ifnull(count(*), 0). Neither gave me the result I was looking for.

Comment: I would like to add that I have seen the other similar questions, but thus far, none have been able to help me out on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering needs to be in the `on` clause.  And you need to fix the `count()`:

```
SELECT bet.event_abr, COUNT(u.id) as value
FROM basketball_event_types bet LEFT JOIN
     basketball_game_events bge
     ON bet.id = bge.event_type_id AND bge.game_id = 213 LEFT JOIN
     users u 
     ON bge.player_id = u.id AND u.id = 198
WHERE bet.event_abr IN ('TO', 'AST')
GROUP BY bet.event_abr;
```

Note the changes:

- The filtering is moved to the `ON` clauses -- both filters to the appropriate clauses.
- The `COUNT()` counts the values in the last `LEFT JOIN`ed table.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `IN` is simpler than a chain of `OR` conditions.

Comment: Accepting this as the correct answer as soon as it allows. WOW, thank you. Saved me from throwing my laptop out of the window

Comment: Gordon, Can you please share any documentation regarding `The COUNT() counts the values in the last LEFT JOINed table.`

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . Huh?  I don't understand.  `COUNT()` counts the number of non-NULL values of the expression.  The expression is a column from the last table.

Comment: I meant to ask, Is it anywhere documented that count will only count the non-null values of the last joined table. and is it universal law for all databases?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . That is not true.  The statement in the answer is referring to the use of `count()` in this query -- that to do what the OP wants, it needs to refer to a column in the last joined table.